# Loading animation disappear before second ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am showing loading animation whenever ajax call gets started and stops once the ajax call is completed. It works fine when i use only one ajax call in function. However if i have two ajax calls within same function, it seems like the loading animation disappears after first ajax call is complete. 
How can i make it stay until all ajax call is complete?

Thanks.

Javascript in main.js file:

```
//Show loading image on Ajax Start
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      showPleaseWait();
    });

    //Hide loading image on Ajax complete
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      hidePleaseWait();
    });
```

Javascript in Employee page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlEmployeeNumber").change(function () {
                $("#log").ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                    alert(exception);
                });

                var employeeNumberSelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();

                $.get('@Url.Action("EmployeeSelfServiceInfo")',
                    { chosenEmployeeNumber: employeeNumberSelected }, function (data) {
                        $("#EmployeeSelfServiceInfo").html(data);
                    });

                $.get('@Url.Action("GetEmployeeName")',
                    { chosenEmployeeNumber: employeeNumberSelected }, function (data) {
                        $("#employeeName").text(data);
                    });
            });
        });
</script>




function showPleaseWait() {
    var modalLoading = '<div class="modal" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false role="dialog">\
        <div class="modal-dialog">\
            <div class="modal-content">\
                <div class="modal-header">\
                    <b>Processing...</b>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body center-block">\
                    <div class="progress">\
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"\
                      aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%;">\
                          Please Wait...\
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
    $(document.body).append(modalLoading);
    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("show");
}

 function hidePleaseWait() {
    $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal("hide");
}
```

UPDATE: **So i got it to fixed by replacing existing .ajaxComplete call with .ajaxStop call.**

Comment: `showPleaseWait();` share the code for this and for hide and html.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep a variable to track mutiple ajax calls.

```
var ajaxCallCounter=0;
//Show loading image on Ajax Start
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  showPleaseWait();
});

//Hide loading image on Ajax complete
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  if(ajaxCallCounter===0)
  {
    hidePleaseWait();
  }
});
```

Every time you make an ajax call, increase this variable. When your ajax call gets a response from server, decrease it.

```
ajaxCallCounter++;
$.get('@Url.Action("EmployeeSelfServiceInfo")',function(res){
   ajaxCallCounter--;
   //do something with the  res
});
```

In the above example, we used a simple global variable (*Which is not so good*) !.You may use javascript namespacing for declaring the variable to prevent possible overwriting of the value of this variable or wrap your code inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter.

- On start increment it,
- On complete, decrement it.
- Check to see if it is zero. If it is, hide it.

Basic idea:

```
(function(){

    var openCount = 0;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      openCount++;
      showPleaseWait();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      openCount--;
      if(!openCount) hidePleaseWait();
    });

}());
```

Comment: tried this but i still don't see the difference. :(

Comment: What is the show and hide code doing? Maybe the issue is in there now. Or change it to be `if(openCount===1) showPleaseWait();` Code should work since I do something just like this.

Comment: i have updated the original post to include showPleaseWait and hidePleaseWait functions.

Comment: Why are you incrementing in the hide? And since you are creating multiple modals, you probably should only append it if it is not on the page to start. And you should not call the showPleaseWait if open.

Comment: epascarello actually i saw your answer and modified the wrong function and edited the original question with the code for hidePleaseWait. I fixed the original question without the openCount++ for hidePleaseWait. Btw, i got it to work by using .ajaxStop instead of .ajaxComplete now. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -2):

don't use ajaxStart and ajaxComplete, you can bind those calls to each `$.get` instead:

```
            $.get('@Url.Action("EmployeeSelfServiceInfo")',
                { chosenEmployeeNumber: employeeNumberSelected }, 
                beforeSend: showPleaseWait,
                complete:  hidePleaseWait,
                function (data) {
                    $("#EmployeeSelfServiceInfo").html(data);
                });


            $.get('@Url.Action("GetEmployeeName")',
                { chosenEmployeeNumber: employeeNumberSelected },  
                beforeSend: showPleaseWait,
                complete:  hidePleaseWait,
                function (data) {
                    $("#employeeName").text(data);
                });
```

The problem is that since those are async calls, the hide/show on those elements will look weird, probably.

Comment: WHY NOT use them? Bad advice. Code does not answer OPs question on how not to hide.

Comment: and if last one takes a lot longer than other ... OP is back to square one. This has exact same behavior as what OP currently has ... with more code involved

Comment: also note your syntax is incorrect for passing function references

Comment: I didn't say he can't do as many ajax calls as he wants, the problem is that he's trying to display the statuses of them with the same dom elements... that's it

Comment: *"How can i make it stay until all ajax call is complete?*" Yours does not do that.... Your code is 100% the same as the OPs.